# Excel freezes when deleting a column with a custom XLL C++ functions

Tags: c++, excel, freeze, xll

I created a custom function "SumCells" for calculating the sum of cells. When I run it on 1,000,000 cells (in one column), it counts quickly, but when I try to delete it, Excel freezes for a long time. I think it has to do with freeing up memory. Who can give advice, please help. Maybe you have a link to a real example of such a function.

My code:

```
#define g_rgNumUDFs 1
#define g_rgUDFdata 11

#include <windows.h>
#include "XLCALL.H"
#include "FRAMEWRK.H"

static LPWSTR g_rgUDFs
[g_rgNumUDFs][g_rgUDFdata] =

{
    {
        L"SumCells",              // Function name/ordinal
        L"BQ",                    // Func signature type
        L"SumCells",              // Func name in Func wizard
        L"Arg1",                  // Arg name in Func wizard
        L"1",                     // Function type
        L"SimpleXll2020",         // Category in Func wizard
        L"",                      // Shortcut (commands only)
        L"",                      // Help topic
        L"Sum data",              // Func help in Func wizard
        L"Help for Arg1",         // Arg help in Func wizard
        L""
    }
};

__declspec(dllexport) double SumCells(XLOPER12& arg1)
{
    double result = 0;

    size_t numCols = arg1.val.array.columns;
    size_t numRows = arg1.val.array.rows;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numCols * numRows; ++i)
    {
        result += arg1.val.array.lparray[i].val.num;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must at least check the type of XLOPERs (xltypeStr, xltypeNum...) and access the data correctly (arrays are row-major) :

```
double result = 0;
if ((arg1.xltype & xltypeMulti) !=0)
{    
        size_t numCols = arg1.val.array.columns;
        size_t numRows = arg1.val.array.rows;
        for (int r=0;r<numRows ;r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < numCols; c++)
            {
                LPXLOPER12 cell = arg1.val.array.lparray + ((r * numCols) + c);
                if ((cell->xltype & xltypeNum) !=0)
                    result += cell->val.num;
            }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the examples included with the SDK download (eg the "FuncSum" example in the GENERIC.C file in the GENERIC XLL example) use LPXLOPER12 pointers and 'U' as the parameter type. You have chosen to pass an XLOPER12& reference and use the 'Q' parameter type in the function registration.

Though I am not an expert on the API, the reference suggests that type "Q" involves some processing of the data array before passing (eg converting range references into an array of values), and hence possibly some memory clean-up after. My recollection of the 'U' type is that it is a more direct pointer to the passed data array.

From the reference:
*"When DLL function arguments are registered as taking type P XLOPERs or type Q XLOPER12s, Excel converts single-cell references to simple values and multi-cell references to arrays when preparing these arguments."*

[Link to xlfRegister from SDK reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/xlfregister-form-1)